# Changing the email on stackoverflow.com web site

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I would like to change my email address that I used on Stack Overflow site(s).  That email is a gmail address, but it happens to be my secondary gmail. My main one is another gmail address.

When I signed up with Stack Overflow site, I happened to sign up with using the gmail login process, instead of creating a regular account at Stack Overflow or happened to go with my real gmail. And as a result of that bad decision at that moment, now every time I need to login to the Stack Overflow web site from a new computer/device, I must make sure that I'm also logged into that second gmail account! Well, on the note 3, that becomes a problem cause the device wants one and only gmail address.

The question is this:

Can I edit my Stack Overflow preferences so that it's now pointing to my main gmail? Would that take care of the problem, or would that awfully complicate things?

And also, is this something that I need to worry about at stackexchange.com level or site by site basis which is an affiliate of the stackexchange network?

Comment: Questions about your account and other questions about SO's operation should be posted to [meta] instead. This site is strictly for programming and programmers tools related questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to your profile page, at the top-right below the `Ask Question` button there should be a link labeled: `my logins`.

[image: my logins link]

Here you can add and remove multiple Google accounts.

[image: manage account links]

Comment: I couldn't have more than one Google account attached so I created another type (Facebook), removed the old Google account and set the new I wanted to use.

Comment: Please update your answer because the site has been updated since you posted your existing answer.